# New module configuration in zend framework 2

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create restful api module with zend framework 2.

I'm unable to create proper module.config.php

My folder structure for new module is:

```
[...]/module/Api
[...]/module/Api/config
[...]/module/Api/src/Api/Controller
```

My controller is named: ShortenerController.php located in
    [...]/module/Api/src/Api/Controller/ShortenerController.php

In it I have namespace setted as:

```
namespace Api\Controller;
```

In [...]/module/Api/config I have module.config.php file which has this code:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Api\Controller\Shortener' => 'Api\Controller\ShortenerController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'Api' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/api/s/[:url]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'API\Controller\Shortener',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),


  'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
//         'template_map' => array(
//             'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
//             'index/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/index/index.phtml',
//             'error/404'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
//             'error/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
//         ),
//         'template_path_stack' => array(
//             'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
//         ),
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
    ),
);
```

When I'm trying to invoke curl with post data to this link:

```
http://server_address/api/s/
```

I'm getting error such as this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Api\\Controller\\ShortenerController' not found in /home/ertai/zf/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170
```

What I'm doing here wrong? I can't get a grasp on what I should write into module.config.php file in order to have proper route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to declare your module in `application.config.php` like this :

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Api',
    ),
```

And by the way, take care in your default route configuration

```
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'API\Controller\Shortener',
                ),
```

This is case-sensitive, so it should be :

```
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Api\Controller\Shortener',
                ),
```

And I advise you to set a default action too like this :

```
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Api\Controller\Shortener',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
```

Comment: Yes it was case sensitive inaccuracy. Thank you for spotting that. It wasn't the main issue - the wrong namespace was in Module.php. Regardless I've changed many times API for Api and vice versa and skipped this issue you've found before posting on stack. Thank you!